# Automatically Change Model Value If Another Value Updates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

With Laravel & Eloquent, if a column called `status` changes its value to "complete," for example, is it possible to automatically change the value of another column (`issue_id`) to NULL?

I was wondering about the set attribute or intercepting the save() method, but not sure which is best.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events).

For example, to observe the `Issue` model, you could generate an Observer as such:

```
php artisan make:observer IssueObserver --model=Issue
```

This will produce an observer where you could listen to many model events.

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Issue;

class IssueObserver
{

    /**
    * Handle the Issue "updating" event.
    *
    * @param  \App\Issue  $Issue
    * @return void
    */
    public function updating(Issue $issue)
    {
        if($issue->status == 'complete') {
            $issue->issue_id = null;
        }
    }
}
```

To register the Observer, you would need to add this to `AppServiceProvider@boot()`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Issue;
use App\Observers\IssueObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        Issue::observe(IssueObserver::class);
    }

    /**
    * Register the service provider.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You could also just do this in your `App/Issue` model.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); 

    static::updating(function ($issue) {
        if($issue->status == 'complete') {
            $issue->issue_id = null;
        }
    })
}
```

Obviously, you would need to listen on the events that suit your needs. This is just an example. You could take a look at all the available model events [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events).

Comment: calling `save` in `updated` does this not call infinitly `updated` ?